# Python - Clearing and resetting Text widgit - Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm having a heck of time clearing this text wigit. I'll admit that I'm new to python and its GUI API, but I've read the documention and tried the suggestions on Stack Overflow to no avail.

I've seen many people suggest: `self.text.delete(0.0, 'end')`

this however is not working in the listener. Oddly it does work if I put it in the constructor. I get not stack trace from the listener either. Below is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Text

def main():
    CalculatorGUI(CalculatorController())

class CalculatorController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ans = "0"

    def calculate(self, textBox):
        value = str("")
        try:
            inputValue = textBox.replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
            if inputValue[:1] in "-*/+%":
                value = str(eval(self.ans + inputValue))[::-1]
            else:
                value = str(eval(inputValue))[::-1]

            return self.makeHumanReadable(value)
        except:
            return "I cannot math that!"

    def makeHumanReadable(self, stringValue):
        if "." in stringValue:
            decimal = stringValue[:stringValue.index(".")]
            integer = stringValue[stringValue.index(".") + 1:]  
            self.ans = (decimal + "." + (','.join(integer[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(integer), 3))))[::-1]\
                                        .replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
            print("Current answer is: " + self.ans)
            return (decimal + "." + (','.join(integer[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(integer), 3))))[::-1]

        else:
            self.ans = ','.join(stringValue[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(stringValue), 3))[::-1] \
                                                            .replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
            return ','.join(stringValue[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(stringValue), 3))[::-1]


class CalculatorGUI:
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.frame1 = tkinter.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.frame1)

        self.text = BetterText(self.frame1, height=1, borderwidth=0)
        self.text.insert(1.0, "Enter a math statement:")
#       self.text.delete(0.0, 'end')   # If this is not commented out, it deletes 
                                       # the text but not when put in the listener

#       self.text.clearAll()           # Same here
        self.text.configure(state="disabled")

        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frame2, width = 30)
        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(self.frame2, text="Calculate", \
                            command=self.calculate)

        self.text.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.calcButton.pack()

        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def calculate(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")
        self.text.clearAll() # Does not work
        if self.entry.get() != "":
            self.text.insert("END", self.controller.calculate(self.entry.get()))


main()
```

Any ideas??? Using Python 3.4

EDIT: I even tried extending the Text widget and making a clearAll() method. Again it works in the constructor but not in the listener and it throws no errors. Its likely that there is a problem somewhere else in the code and I just don't see it.

```
class BetterText(Text):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw): 
        Text.__init__(self, master, kw)

    def clearAll(self):
        self.delete(0.0, 'end')
```

Comment: Please show the error you get. The correct way to delete everything from a text widget is pretty close to what you say: `self.text.delete("1.0", "end")`

Comment: Thats the issue, I'm not getting an error. I put a print statement in the listener to see if it's even executing.. which it is. But I get no error

Comment: Give the code a try, should be copy/paste/execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using the text.configure(state="disabled") and then trying to write to the widget. In python, disabling the text box means that the user can't edit it, but it also means you can't. The reason your commented out code worked was that it came before the line you disabled the text widget. Try adding text.configure(state="normal") in your clear method before you attempt to change the text widget, and then set the state back when you are done. That seemed to fix the problem when I tried it out.